# KendoUI Grid dynamic server filtering/sorting based on result count

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there any way to make Kendo Grid not use server side filtering/sorting when there are less than X results?

i.e. If the the initial row count comes back from the server as being 8, is it possible to make subsequent filtering and sorting requests to run on that local data-set rather than querying the server again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switching serverSorting/serverFiltering after initialization is possible but you need to set all server* settings to true/false.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataBound: function() {
    this.dataSource.options.serverSorting = false;
    this.dataSource.options.serverPaging = false;
    this.dataSource.options.serverFiltering = false;
  }
});
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/aqaxoq/1/edit

Comment: What about calling dataSource.query({serverFiltering: false}) in an if statement?

Comment: I have mislead you. Changing serverSorting/serverFiltering seems possible.